# What happens when WebSockets aren't supported using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

What happpens when the  current environment does not support WebSockets using socket.io?

Answer (score 5):

All socket.io connections by default will connect using longpolling. If successfully connected it will then automatically attempt to upgrade the connection to use websockets. If the websocket connection succeeds it will continue to use the websocket for all communication. If unsuccessful, it continue to communicate using longpolling.

Comment: thanks a lot. so it's from down and up while I thought up to down